# Using pyspark to create a large precomputed cosine similarity matrix from text data

Tags: python, similarity, pyspark, cosine-distance, matrix

I would like to precompute a cosine similarity matrix for a large dataset (upwards of 5 million rows) using pyspark.

Here's what I have so far.

libraries:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer, NGram, StopWordsRemover, RegexTokenizer, Normalizer
```

clean and tokenize the data - I am removing spaces and tokenizing the data this way to process the string of text as an ngram later:

```
data = spark_df.select('item_id',
    F.regexp_replace('product_name', r',|\.|&|\\|\||-|_|–|/|<html>|(|)| |', '').alias('product_name'))

tokenizer = RegexTokenizer(pattern="", inputCol="product_name", outputCol="tokens", minTokenLength=1)

wordsData = tokenizer.transform(data)
```

compute ngrams

```
ngram = NGram(n=4, inputCol="tokens", outputCol="ngrams")
ngramDataFrame = ngram.transform(wordsData)
df = ngramDataFrame.withColumn("ngrams", F.expr("""transform(ngrams,x-> regexp_replace(x,"\ ",""))"""))
```

compute IDF (ngram frequency) and standardize

```
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="ngrams", outputCol="rawFeatures", numFeatures=20)
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(df)

idf = IDF(inputCol="rawFeatures", outputCol="features").fit(featurizedData)
rescaledData = idf.transform(featurizedData) 

normalizer = Normalizer(inputCol="features", outputCol="norm")
data = normalizer.transform(rescaledData)
```

convert results in indexed row matrix and transpose (to use built-in columnSimilarities function)

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import IndexedRow, IndexedRowMatrix

mat = IndexedRowMatrix(
    data.select("item_id", "norm")\
        .rdd.map(lambda row: IndexedRow(row.item_id, row.norm.toArray()))).toBlockMatrix().transpose().toIndexedRowMatrix()

pred_sims = mat.columnSimilarities()
```

And then I would like to have the final matrix

```
pred_sims.toLocalMatrix().toArray()
```

The problem is even using only 100 rows this takes well over 30 mins and results in a matrix too large to load

```
IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The length of the values array must 
be less than Int.MaxValue. Currently numRows * numCols: 10140959066024241
```

This is something I could do in scikit learn using thousands of rows but I can't seem to process even a small dataset using Spark. I'm a spark beginner; is there just something obviously wrong with my methods or my syntax?